# Run .exe with argument on remote ssh command

Tags: ssh

Have to figure out how to add argument/variable on remote ssh command. If I run following command without argument then it works fine:

**ssh user@host \folder1\folder11 .\file.exe**

but have not figured out how to add argument. Have tested:

ssh user@host '\folder1\folder11 .\file.exe $argument' -> the system cannot find the path specified
ssh user@host '\folder1\folder11 .\file.exe "$arument"' -> the system cannot find the path specified
ssh user@host "\folder1\folder11 .\file.exe argument" -> network path was not found

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What operating system are you invoking ssh on? Windows or unix/linux?

Comment: Windows... command prompt